# Problems with openshift and package six

Tags: python, package, openshift, six

I have an openshift application and I need to use a `APScheduler` package which needs `six==1.9.0` package.

If I do `pip install six==1.9.0` I get:

```
Collecting six==1.9.0
  Downloading six-1.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.wh
Installing collected packages: six
  Found existing installation: six 1.3.0
    Not uninstalling six at /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages, outside environment /var/lib/openshift/5764a66a0c1e66c49700006b/python/virtenv/venv
Successfully installed six-1.3.0
```

So it is not install the version I need. I tried to uninstall `pip uninstall six==1.3.0` but I get this:

```
Not uninstalling six at /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages, outside environment /var/lib/openshift/5764a66a0c1e66c49700006b/python/virtenv/venv
```

I also tried on doing it with `sudo` but I have read that is impossible to do `sudo` commands in openshift application.

Any idea?

Comment: You say you get that output when you "do `pip install six==1.9.0`. Can you elaborate a bit on how you're doing that? Is it part of some `openshift` config? I don't personally know much about `openshift`, so I can't help directly, but this seems like an issue with how the `pip` command is interacting with the environment in some way.

Comment: Instead of using pip add your Six==1.9.0 in your "requires" in the setup.py.  When you push to Openshift it should install the correct one.  Or try easy_install.